# Can I use 1 optocoupler to drive 4 MOSFETs?

Tags: mosfet, optoelectronics

I've this circuit and works correctly, now I need to control 4 MOSFET instead of 2, is the second schematic correctly?
[image]

[image]

Comment: How is that +12V related to the MOSFETs? What switching speed are we talking about?

Comment: this circuit needs the mosfets to switch once every 5 minutes (not pwm, that's why I didn't put a driver), does 12V reach all gates?

Comment: Yes, I think PC817 can drive many more than 4 MOSFETs.

Comment: If you don't mind that switching takes up to a second then the PC817 can switch **hundreds** of MOSFETs. Realize that MOSFETs have a high impedance input (gate) and behave largely as a **capacitor** (to the source).

Comment: You didn’t answer my question: What’s the relationship between +12V and A-, B-, OUT1 and OUT2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> this circuit needs the mosfets to switch once every 5 minutes (not pwm, that's why I didn't put a driver), does 12V reach all gates? – Ricardo Casimiro 4 mins ago

Yes all the current is drawn by the 10k resistor to 11.7V with Vce(sat) on the opto. or > 1mA

This works well with 4mA input or more.

If using 3.3V input (3.3V-1.2)/(220+25 cmos) = 8.5mA

If using 5V 220 Ohms is overkill but OK.